# Find the third largest element in the array in linear time

Tags: java, programming-challenge, interview-questions

> Find Third largest element in an array
>
> Input  : arr[] = {1, 14, 2, 16, 10, 20}
>
> Output : 14

Its a simple program, but would be great to know how it can be improved for better readability or any feedback regarding styling, etc.

```
public static int findThirdLargest(int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length < 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("there should be at least three numbers");
    }

    int largest, secondLargest, thirdLargest;
    largest = secondLargest = thirdLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int number : numbers) {

        if (number > largest) {
            thirdLargest = secondLargest;
            secondLargest = largest;
            largest = number;
        } else if (number > secondLargest) {
            thirdLargest = secondLargest;
            secondLargest = number;
        } else if (number > thirdLargest) {
            thirdLargest = number;
        }
    }

    return thirdLargest;
}


@Test
public void findThirdLargest() throws Exception {

    // with positive numbers
    Assert.assertEquals(1, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{1, 2, 3}));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4}));
    Assert.assertEquals(2, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{1, 4, 3, 2}));
    Assert.assertEquals(14, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{1, 14, 2, 16, 10, 20}));
    Assert.assertEquals(16, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{19, -10, 20, 14, 2, 16, 10}));

    // with negative numbers
    Assert.assertEquals(-100, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{-100, -2, -3}));
    Assert.assertEquals(-3, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{1, 2, -3, -1000}));
    Assert.assertEquals(-3000, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{-1000, -2000, -3000, -4000, -5000}));

    // what happens when all the numbers are same
    Assert.assertEquals(1, ThirdLargestNumber.findThirdLargest(new int[]{1, 1, 1, 1}));
}
```

Code: https://github.com/Ramblers-Code/CodeKata/blob/master/src/main/java/kata/array/ThirdLargestNumber.java#5

Comment: Please clarify how ties are supposed to be treated.

Answer (score 1):

I think overall it is well done, it is clear and readable. Some general tips:

- You can make the parameter a `varargs`, which makes it easier to call:

  ```
  public static int findThirdLargest(int... numbers)
  ...
  int thirdLargest = findThirdLargest(1, 2, 3);
  ```
- Since you check for the size of the array, you could perhaps also check if it is not `null`.
- This is somewhat personal, but I would always declare and initialise each variable on a separate line, e.g.:

  ```
  int largest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int secondLargest = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  int thirdLargest= Integer.MIN_VALUE;
  ```

To me it helps readability and potentially refactoring later on.

- I'd remove the newline after the `for` loop opener. It decreases readability for me.

Nice that you added tests! You covered some good cases. You could take a look at `Hamcrest` matchers, you can create some nice declarative tests with it. They can also show quite decent messages in case a test fails.

Some extra tips about the current tests:

- I'd split up the tests in a couple of different methods
- Personally, I like to use static imports, so you can write:

  ```
  assertEquals(1, findThirdLargest(1, 2, 3))
  ```
- Also do not forget to test for failing cases. Test that when you pass less than 3 numbers, you expect an exception.

And what should the output of `findThirdLargest(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)` be?

Lastly, a follow up exercise: how would you implement it if the user wants to find the `k`-th largest element?